# How to get number of partial matches using re2

Tags: c++, re2

I want to get number of sub-string matches of a given string using re2;

I have read the codes of re2: https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/re2/re2.h but do not see an easy way to do that.

I have following sample code:

```cpp
std::string regexPunc = "[\\p{P}]"; // matches any punctuations; 
re2::RE2 re2Punc(regexPunc);
std::string sampleString = "test...test";
if (re2::RE2::PartialMatch(sampleString, re2Punc)) {
    std::cout << re2Punc.numOfMatches();
}
```

I want it to output 3 as there are three punctuations in the string;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FindAndConsume`, and count the matches yourself. It won't be inefficient, because in order to know the number of matches, those matches would have to be performed and counted anyway.

Example:

```
std::string regexPunc = "[\\p{P}]"; // matches any punctuations; 
re2::RE2 re2Punc(regexPunc);
std::string sampleString = "test...test";
StringPiece input(sampleString);
int numberOfMatches = 0;
while(re2::RE2::FindAndConsume(&input, re2Punc)) {
    ++numberOfMatches;
}
```