# get all the matches from re2 PartialMatch with dynamic number of capturing group

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I want to use `RE2::PartialMatch` but the number of capturing group is dynamic, so I can't just do it this way:

```
string a, b, c; //fix amount of results
RE2::PartialMatch(text, regex, &a, &b, &c);
```

Is there a way to do it similar to this:

```
vector<string> vec(reg.NumberOfCapturingGroups());
RE2::PartialMatchN(object_name, reg, reg.NumberOfCapturingGroups(), reg.NumberOfCapturingGroups());
```

Comment: `FindAndConsume` as in [how-to-get-number-of-partial-matches-using-re2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56418122/how-to-get-number-of-partial-matches-using-re2)

Comment: FindAndConsume works for unknown amount of matches, not unknown amount of capturing groups